# html5 video draws black box (empty) to canvas

Tags: javascript, html, html5-video

I'm dynamically loading and drawing the first frame little video elements to a bigger canvas. (when you rollover it plays them) It usually works (90% of the time) but randomly sometimes one or other of the videos will draw a black box signifying that the imagedata sampled from the video is empty.

How I'm doing this is to use the `canplaythrough` event on each of the videos to identify if the video is ready to be sampled but I'm wondering if there is a better event I should be using?

for instance:

```
myvid.addEventListener("canplaythrough",function()
        {
            //do the sampling now
        });
```

but the above occasionally and seemingly randomly draws a blank?

Any ideas? I've also tried: `onloadeddata` and `canplay` but these were even less reliable

Answer (score 0):

I feel reason of blank frame is,even a one second video also consists of lots of frames. So it may contain a blank frame in between. I feel the event canplaythrough is proper. You may modify your sampling logic.

```
 myvid.addEventListener("canplaythrough",function()
        {
           //check the intensity of some pixels of sample if they are blank. If blank then raise canplaythrough event
//else do the sampling now
        });
```

Comment: that would be nice but nope.. 90% of the time the video shows the first frame as expected. If I refresh the page a few times (there are about 5-7 videos on the canvas at any point) 1 or 2 of them randomly will be a blank box